# How to know that a mysql user defined function is compiled every time its called and stored procedure is not compiled every time its called

Tags: mysql

How to know that a MYSQL user defined function is compiled every time its called and stored procedure is executed once and is not compiled every time when its called.Can someone give me any example.

Comment: User-defined functions are compiled when you compile the C code that defines it.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for replying but i am asking about the MYSQL user defined function and Stored Procedure.

Comment: Those are called stored procedures, not user-defined functions. I don't think they're compiled at all.

Comment: i was reading this post 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-function-and-procedure/?ref=rp
Can you help me with it.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. So it seems like you have your answer.